# after going into fullscreen using webkitRequestFullscreen scrollTop(0) does not work

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, html5-fullscreen

I am going into fullscreen using `$("body")[0].webkitRequestFullscreen();`.

However, when I try to use ScrollTop it does not work.

I am using this:

```
$('html, body').scrollTop(0);
```

It works fine in firefox but does nothing in chrome. I have tried using delays or animation. Both failed.

```
while $(window).scrollTop() returns 0.
```

If I go into fullscreen using F11 then scrollTop works fine. The reason why I am using `requestFullScreen` is because I want to go into fullscreen on a selected portion of my webpage.